# Custom Keyboard: ASCII Codes vs KEYCODE

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a Gamer's Keyboard for Android. The idea is to emulate several different layouts that are more centric to gamers.

I've come across something that I would like advice on. The current `android:codes` use ASCII values (http://www.asciitable.com/). There are several keys that do not have an ASCII value assigned to them. I do see that there are KEYCODES for many keys though (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent). Can these be used in place of ASCII values in `android:codes`? How could I use this in the following example:

**QWERTY.XML**

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="49,33" android:keyLabel="1" android:popupCharacters="1!"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50,64" android:keyLabel="2"  android:popupCharacters="2@"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="51,35" android:keyLabel="3"  android:popupCharacters="3#"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="52,36" android:keyLabel="4"  android:popupCharacters="4$"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="53,37" android:keyLabel="5"  android:popupCharacters="5%"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="54,94" android:keyLabel="6"  android:popupCharacters="6^"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="55,38" android:keyLabel="7"  android:popupCharacters="7&amp;"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="56,42" android:keyLabel="8"  android:popupCharacters="8*"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="57,40" android:keyLabel="9"  android:popupCharacters="9("
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="48,41" android:keyLabel="0"  android:popupCharacters="0)"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keypopup"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
        android:keyWidth="20%p"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

Will I need to add anything to the Java file?

I do have to admit, that this is my first time working on an Android app. I am using Android Studio 3. For the most part, I have it working, there are some things I need to work out, etc. The above would help out though. :D

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I expect you're going to hit a wall soon.  No serious keyboard actually uses KeyboardView-  its very limiting.   Most use a custom view, and then they don't need to worry about stuff like this.